# A class of 46 form groups each of which contains exactly three members so that any two groups have at most one member in common. Prove that...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Students in a class form groups each of which contains exactly three members such that any two distinct groups have at most one member in common. Prove that, when the class size is $ 46$, there is a set of
>
> - a) $ 7$;
> - b) $10$ students in which no group is properly contained.

For a) Say we have $n$ sets. Since each pair of students is in at most one of these sets and each set contains 3 pairs, we have $${46\choose 2}\geq 3n \implies n\leq 345$$ Let's take at random and independetly a student with a probability $p={1\over 5}$. Let $X$ be a number of choosen students and $Y$ be a number of "bad" subsets i.e. number of subsets among those $n$ that are entirely in the set of choosen students. Then we have $$E(X-Y) = 46p-np^3\geq {46\over 5} -{345\over 125}>6$$
and thus we have a set of $7$ as demanded.

*Now, my question is why this does not work for $b)$?*

*And is there a way to overcome this situation?*

**Note: I know how to solve b) without probabilistic method, so don't need nonprobabilistic solution for it.**

Comment: Because not every method works for every problem? -- Probabilistically, you show that a "typical" choice of students is good, whereas we want to sho that a "well chosen" set of students is good